# as3 collision with classes not on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, class, hittest

sorry to be a pain, i have a main character in my game who can be moved by drag and drop, he has his own class - TamCharacter
i also have a class for Draggable objects
which i have various food items extend from.
this has all been set up to cause collision with the TamCharacter and then remove them from the stage.
However when i drag my character around the top of the screen he collides with the objects even though they are not there.

it then throws up this error:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Vegetable/gravity()

this is gravity:

```
if (this.hitTestObject(tO)) // tO is my TamChar
            {
                trace("collide");

                this.parent.removeChild(this);
                this.y=-30; //i move it out the way just to ensure it doesnt double collide
                this.x=210;
                var hungerValue = 20;



                tO.eatFood(hungerValue); //eatFood is a function in TamChar which increases his health


                trace("object eaten", hungerValue);

            }
```

any help would be amazing thanks,

Comment: Need more code.  Need line number where the error occurs.  Turn on debugging mode in Publish settings.

Comment: You're probably running this within an ENTER_FRAME loop while the Vegetable is off stage. That means there's no parent, and `this.parent` is null.